# Does Windows 10 use the same key when installed with a Win8 key?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, license

Long story short, I helped a friend build a PC a year ago and now we need to reinstall Windows. Originally, he bought a Windows 8.1 Pro license, and I installed Windows 10 with the 8.1 key, (did NOT upgrade).

But now, when reinstalling, he was wondering if I could install 8 instead of 10. However, he can't find the COA and Win8 disc.

So the question is, if I use Magical Jellybean Keyfinder or some similar tool, will the key it reports for the Win10 installation be the same as what we originally input, or is it different due to how the digital entitlement thing works?

I ask because I know if you upgrade to Win10 everybody gets the same generic key...

Comment: “Originally, he bought a Windows 8.1 Pro license, and I installed Windows 10 with the 8.1 key, (did NOT upgrade).“ - Hate to break it to you but this is considered an upgrade the process you used is identical if you upgraded to windows 10 from within Windows 8.1 or if you install Sindows 10 with a 8.1 key.  However if he purchased a key that means he purchase a retail license, so the only place that license exists, is on the sticker that came with the disk.  No other copy exists and license key program cannot and will not display the 8.1 key.

Comment: Magical Jellybean Keyfinder is displaying the generic Windows 10 Professional license key, the same key, everyone that accepted the upgrade uses.

Comment: @Ramhound Well that's why I was asking :) Btw, it's actually a system builder license, not a retail. (Well it was *supposed* to be a retail license, but the Amazon seller sent a system builder one instead and he didn't want to pursue it)

Comment: System Builder licensees are “retail” licenses when dealing with 8.1 but that isn’t the case when dealing with any other version of Windows (yeah I know it’s con) but the license should be printed on the envelope that the disk came with, no license, then your friend will have to purchase a new license

Comment: @Ramhound Well shoot then, I was afraid of that. So either he needs to find that envelope, or Win10 is the only option, correct?

Comment: I assume the original installation, where he used the Windows 8.1, no longer exists?

Comment: @Ramhound Win8.1 was never installed. Win10 was installed with the 8.1 key

Comment: I never said Windows 8.1 was installed.  Please read my comment closely, I asked if the (original) Windows 10 installation (the one the 8.1 was used to install it) was still accessible.  Windows 10 was implied by the statement, "original installation", because that is the only possible meaning.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh sorry, yes, the original Win10 installation does still exist and is still bootable.

Comment: `ShowKeyPlus` is one of the few programs that will actually show the Windows 8.1 key that was used.  `Magical Jellybean Keyfinder` is trash software, which barely works, and most of the time doesn't even display accurate results.

Comment: @Ramhound It will recover the key even if it isn't embedded in the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Please know that the digital license can only work for Windows 10, to reinstall Windows 8.1 and reactivate as you would like, you may need to find the COA. Luckily, there’s a free utility called ShowKeyPlus that will find it for you.

https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus

ShowKeyPlus will reveal your product key and license information such as:

Product Name

Product ID

The currently installed key, which is the generic product key used by Windows 10 depending on the edition installed.

**The Original product key. This can be your Windows 7 or Windows 8 retail or OEM product key before upgrading. This is the product key you want if you encounter product activation issues in Windows 10.**

OEM Key OR Retail: ShowKeyPlus will check for the presence of an OEM marker; that is how big name vendors activate multiple machines at the factory running Windows.

Comment: The author is asking how to install Windows 8.1 not Windows 10

Comment: Yes, I see, I just would like to let OP know that the digital license can only be used to activate Windows 10. I have customized my post. Thanks for your kind reminder.

Comment: But is that utility only for extracting an embedded key from the BIOS? As this was a custom built machine there is no key in the BIOS AFAIK

Comment: @KateLi The question has nothing to do with that digital entitlement though

Answer (score 0):

Once you use the Windows 8.1 key to activate Windows 10, Windows 10 will create a digital entitlement. The product key stored on the system will be converted to a generic key.

**You cannot recover your Windows 8.1 key from the Windows 10 system.**

Seriously, not trying to be mean, but friends don't let friends use Windows 8. There is absolutely no valid reason to want to do this and you should explain that.

Comment: The author is asking how to install Windows 8.1 not Windows 10

Comment: I would use Windows 8.1 over Windows 10. As far as I'm concerned, Windows 10 is an utter piece of garbage with spyware automatically turned back on with each update and forced automatic Windows updates.

Comment: Lol. Ok. Maybe you should unplug your Internet connection now and don the shiny hat.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm a Linux user :)